# Actualizar data de chart.js (grafico de barra) mediante Ajax + PHP

Tags: php, ajax, chart.js

Estoy tratando de actualizar un gráfico de barras (chart.js). 
Para ello, trato de crear una función que me permita enviar dos parámetros desde javascript a PHP (a través de Ajax).
La sintaxis es la siguiente:

```js
function updateCumplimientoMensual(filial,detalle)
{
  
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "com01datav2.php",
    
    data: {"filial":filial,"detalle":detalle},
      success: function(respuesta)
      {
        console.log(respuesta);
        myLineChart.data = respuesta;
        myLineChart.update();
      }
  });
};
```

El archivo com01datav2.php que procesa los parametros y devuelve la informacion que sirve de data del grafico, es el siguiente:

```html
<?php

$Datos = "{
    labels: ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','".$_POST['filial']."','".$_POST['detalle']."'],
    datasets: 
      [
        {
        label: 'Real',
        backgroundColor: '#28a745',
        borderColor: '#28a745',
        data: [60,70,80,90,100,60,70,80,90,100,60]
        },
        {
        label: 'Presupuesto',
        backgroundColor: '#007bff',
        borderColor: '#007bff',
        data: [60,70,80,90,100,60,70,80,90,100,60]
        }
      ],
 }";
  echo ($Datos);
?>
```

Lamentablemente, al tratar de actualizar el grafico con la funcion update(), no realiza ninguna variación. Sin embargo, si copio y pego el resultado la cadena que genero desde el archivo php y lo asigno directamente a la linea myLineChart.data, el update si funciona. Ejemplo:

```html
function updateCumplimientoMensual(filial,detalle){
  
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "com01datav2.php",
    
    data: {"filial":filial,"detalle":detalle},
      success: function(respuesta)
      {
        console.log(respuesta);
        //myLineChart.data = respuesta;
        myLineChart.data = {
          labels: ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11'],
          datasets: 
          [
            {
              label: 'Real',
              backgroundColor: '#28a745',
              borderColor: '#28a745',
              data: [60,70,80,90,100,60,70,80,90,100,60]
            },
            {
              label: 'Presupuesto',
              backgroundColor: '#007bff',
              borderColor: '#007bff',
              data: [60,70,80,90,100,60,70,80,90,100,60]
            }
          ],
        };
        myLineChart.update();
      }
  });
};
```

La funcion console.log(respuesta) me imprime en el inspector del navegador lo mismo que asigno de manera directa en el segundo ejemplo.

Agradezco la ayuda.
Roberto

Comment: se me ocurre que puedes destruir la gráfica y escribirla otra vez, highcharts no tiene mucho soporte con ajax, más bien dependiendo de tus parámetros, realizas la gráfica